# Apache - PHP SERVER_ADDR showing internal IP?

Tags: php, apache2

`echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` always yields `192.168.1.142`, which is the IP address of my server within my home network. I can access the website using my external IP since I've set up the port forward on my router, but `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` will only return the internal IP, no matter what I try.

How can I make `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` return my external IP?

Comment: This may be handled through Virtual Host settings where you may already set the intranet IP Address instead of External IP Address

Comment: I don't see the internal IP declared anywhere in the apache settings, nor in any .htaccess files. Would it help if I declared the `ext.ern.al.ip domain.tld` in `/etc/hosts`, and then `ServerName domain.tld` in my virtual host settings? I've got no clue.

Comment: Well I reanalyze and see only /etc/hosts file have impact So you must define your external IP into this file & that will work for your external IP.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I'll take a look at how it was done at work tomorrow on some of our live servers and see what I can find out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use file_get_contents function for this. You just need to find a host which can return your ip address

```
$externalContent = file_get_contents('http://checkip.dyndns.com/');
preg_match('/Current IP Address: ([\[\]:.[0-9a-fA-F]+)</', $externalContent, $myIp);
echo $myexternalIp = $myIp[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a second IP to your server (ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.1.143) and use that in your router's port forwarding rules.  That way, external accesses will be coming in through that address instead and you can tell the difference between the two.